# Intelligent cells taking over the world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, genetic-engineering

Please help me identify this story.  I think it is a short story, not a novel but I could be wrong.

A scientist works on genetically engineering super intelligent cells.  He has some successes.  I don't recall the details but his research comes under scrutiny and the funding agency decides to end the experiment and destroy the test cells.

The scientist decides to save his intelligent cells by ingesting them.

The protagonist first comes down with a terrible illness.  From here on out, the writing is in the style of someone in and out of lucidity.  Essentially the cells are battling the scientist's immune system.  Eventually the intelligent cells win and begin re-engineering the human body for their needs.

Using the human body as a reservoir of resources, they expand, change the human body into more of an amoeba structure and eventually invade the city water supply through the protagonists kitchen sink.

At one point one of his colleagues checks on the scientist and the intelligent amoebas capture him/her (I think it's a her).  The implication is that the cells will eventually destroy the entire human race this way.

Comment: I once came upon a film, on late-night TV, that captured so many point of 'Blood Music' that I can't help but suspect it was a cheaply adaption that I've never been able to find. The redefinition the guys skeleton. His immunity to infection, enhanced senses. The denouement of he and his girlfriend turning into pulsating piles of Connected Stuff. It has to be 'Blood Music' but I have never found it credited. And it actually was not a bad bit of vid. Any clues out there?

Comment: @MickWilson - Ask it as a question...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is Greg Bear's Blood Music. It was originally published as a short story, which you can read online [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791153/9781625791153___2.htm). It was then expanded into a [full novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Music_%28novel%29):

- A scientist works on genetically engineering super intelligent cells - **Check.**
- The scientist decides to save his intelligent cells by ingesting them. - **Check**
- The protagonist first comes down with a terrible illness - **Check.**
- Eventually they invade the city water supply through the protagonist's sink - **Check**

> *Already the plumbing has been invaded. People throughout the building
>   are undergoing transformation.   Within the old time frame of weeks,
>   we will reach the lakes, rivers, and seas in force.*

Comment: I think this is it. Looks like it was originally a short story, and was later expanded into a novel.

Comment: I think it is too and marked it as such.  I'm pretty sure I read the short story and not the novel.

Comment: @Jim2B - If you've read the short story, it's not really worth buying the novel.

Comment: Damn that's a good story.